# MS SQL statements work in DBeaver but not in PHP (with configuration and setup correct)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv, dbeaver

I have the following code to verify that my PHP-MS SQL connection and configuration are setup properly.  I have about 100 getter functions that are all set up the same to retrieve info from this database:

```
function ms_getClientLN($repEnvKey) {
    $repCustKey = '';
    $serverName = "1.1.1.1\\EDGESQL"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"EDGESQL", "UID"=>"userid", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         //echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $sql = "SELECT repCustKey FROM repair WHERE repEnvKey LIKE '$repEnvKey';";
    //echo $sql . "<br>";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    } else {
        #echo "0 results";
    }
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $repCustKey = $row['repCustKey'];
    }
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );

    //----------===== Get ClientLast from customer table =====----------

    $serverName = "1.1.1.1\\EDGESQL"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"EDGESQL", "UID"=>"userid", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $clast = '';
    if( $conn ) {
         //echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $sql = "SELECT cuLastName FROM customers WHERE cuKey LIKE '$repCustKey';";
    //echo $sql . "<br>";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    } else {
        #echo "0 results";
    }
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $clast = $row['cuLastName'];
    }
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );

    return $clast;
}
```

I then have the following function formatted exactly like the other working hundred that produces no results:

```
function ms_getRepairHistory($rhRepKey) {
    $type = '';
    $results[] = array();
    $serverName = "1.1.1.1\\EDGESQL"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"EDGESQL", "UID"=>"userid", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         //echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $sql = "SELECT rhWhen, rhWhereNext, rhNotes FROM RepairHistory WHERE rhRepKey LIKE '$rhRepKey';";
    echo $sql . "<br>";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    } else {
        echo "0 results<br>";
    }
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );
    return $row;
}
```

I'm even echoing the SQL command and can copy and paste it into DBeaver:

```
echo $sql . "<br>";
```

outputs:

```
SELECT rhWhen, rhWhereNext, rhNotes 
FROM RepairHistory 
WHERE rhRepKey LIKE '001-167896-001';
```

Which works in DBeaver with the

```
Databse.dbo.
```

prefix attached:
[image: Photo of command working in DBeaver]

Comment: `return $row;` ... well that's out of scope. Maybe you intended `return $results;`?

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but the output is still 0 results from the SQL query.

Comment: Zhorov, I believe the $connectionInfo contains that schema/database name information, thank you for your reply!

Comment: AlwaysLearning was correct.  I returned the $results variable and it's coming through properly!